# how to handle authentication fails in negative test cases

Tags: authentication, robotframework

I am trying to write test cases to verify the tacacs behaviour. In a negative scenario, when tacacs is stopped and user authentication fails, that is expected behaviour and this test case should be reported as pass. But, when I use the below code, from Robot Framework's SSHLibrary:

```
Open Connection    ${DUT}
Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
```

Immediately when the login attempt fails, its raising an exception with run time error. But, I should handle that exception and should report that as test case PASS. 
Could some one suggest any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should assert the expected exception and set your testdata so it will be raised (under normal circumstances). Then your assert should be true and your test case passes.

Answer (score 2):

When you are testing keywords in a case where they raise exception (negative testing), then you should use keywords like :

- [Run Keyword And Expect Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error)
- [Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error)

For example, if the keyword that fails is "login", then you could do something like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SSHLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
tacacs stopped
    Open Connection  ${DUT}
    Run Keyword And Expect Error  expected_exception_message  Login  ${USERNAME}  ${PASSWORD}
```